# Can someone explain "Authorizing Ownership" (see Railscasts)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, authorization

Can someone explain "Authorizing Ownership"?

I've been going through the [Railscasts' - 7 Security tips](http://railscasts.com/episodes/178-seven-security-tips), and was wondering how is the "current_user.projects.find" implemented?

```
# projects_controller.rb
def show
  @project = current_user.projects.find(params[:id])
end
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Calling a method like "current_user" will first require some kind of authentication system. I recommend you look into [devise](http://railscasts.com/episodes/209-introducing-devise) or [omniauth](http://railscasts.com/episodes/241-simple-omniauth) (allows for Facebook, Twitter, etc).

With regards to the current_user method, as I said, it requires a more complex authentication system and User model for it to make sense. But it is defined as a helper method in ApplicationController.rb like so:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  helper_method :current_user

  private  
  def current_user  
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]  
  end
end
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

This defines user.projects:

```
class User 
  has_many :projects
end
```

Well if you mean that with implemented, otherwise take a look at activerecord source code :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually I realized that the answer is quite simple, and it is in the railscast attached to the post.

Initially the `@project` was retrieved with this construct:

```
def show
  @project = Project.find(params[:id])
end
```

All that was needed was to use the activerecord association by doing

```
@project = current_user.projects.find(params[:id])
```

Comment: Ok, so now how is "current_user" defined? and where? Is it in user.rb?

Comment: current_user would come from your authentication framework, usually.  It represents the logged-in user.